# Combining strings with formatted numbers while incrementing by one

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to pad @myid with zeros but the zeros are not showing up. The results should be in this format(SC000290, SC000291, etc). What is displaying is SC290. Can someone show me how this is done?

```
declare @myid int;
select @myid = 290

SELECT CONCAT('SC', FORMAT(@myid, '000000') + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by (select NULL))) as myid
FROM Table
```

Comment: There are no `bigint`s in that query, that I can see. The only place there is implicit covnerion is in the `FORMAT` and `ROW_NUMBER`, and `FORMAT` is returning a `varchar`, and `ROW_NUMBER` an `int`. The `FORMAT` is also completely pointless, as the value would be implicitly cast to an `int`, removing all the leading zeros.

Comment: Is there an answer here somewhere or are you just handing out explanations?

Comment: There isn't an answer in there, because the code you provide won't generate that error, @FirstElement . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f79f6a434194fa1b1b9e2e7d2b249c6c) Take the time to post a [mre].

Comment: In fact, the code above would fail with the error *"'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name."* `FORMAT` was introducted in SQL Server 2012, and you are using SQL Server 2008 (which, by the way, has been completely unsupported now for 18~ months, so long past time getting to upgrade path sorted).

Comment: You ought to read up on [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It explains why combining a string with an `int` (`FORMAT(@myid, '000000') + ROW_NUMBER()`) results in an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally avoid the use of `FORMAT`, it's a slow function and isn't available in the version of SQL Server you are using anyway; as I stated in the comments:

> `FORMAT` was introducted in SQL Server 2012, and you are using SQL Server 2008 (which, by the way, has been completely unsupported now for 18~ months, so long past time getting to upgrade path sorted).

Instead, you could use `RIGHT` to get the value you wanted, which'll work on  the version you are using, and on more recent versions won't be as costly as `FORMAT`:

```sql
SELECT 'SC' + RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))),6) --YOu should really use a proper column, not (SELECT NULL)
       {Other Columns}
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `row_number()` returns an `int` so the `+` is integer addition, not string concatenation.  So, just use `concat()` all the way through:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SC', 
              FORMAT(@myid, '000000'),
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select NULL))
             ) as myid
FROM Table
```